# Multiple emoji plug-in on same page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a plug-in ([EmojiRating](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Emoji-Rating-Plugin-jQuery.html)) which i used to perform a jquery emoticon rating.

I am trying to put it inside an `asp:DataList` so that for every item it will repeat.

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dtl1" runat="server" DataKeyField="QId"   RepeatLayout="Flow" OnItemDataBound="dtlQuestions_ItemDataBound">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                         <div class="emoji-div" id='<%# Eval("QuestionId") %>'></div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfResponse" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
      </li>
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:DataList>
```

Js

```
 $(".emoji-div").emoji({

                callback: function (event, value) {
                    alert('Current: ' + value);
                }
            });
```

As i have used class (emoji-div) all the rating plug-in will get same value as i rate.

How can I call  `$(".emoji-div").emoji()` function for each item of datalist and record the rating value in each hidden field to get it in c#.

Comment: Looking at the code of the plugin it seems to me that it is a problem within the plugin itself, it does not iterate each item when working with a class. You can iterate each element with your class and instantiate the plugin for each element seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a each loop to iterate over each item

```
$(".emoji-div").each(function(i,v) {
   $(v).emoji({
                callback: function (event, value) {
                    alert('Current: ' + value);
                     $(".emoji-div").each(function(i,v) {
                          var val = $(v).attr('value');
                          $(v).next('input').val(val);
                      });
                }
            });
})
```

Comment: One more issue which i am facing is to get the value of rating in a repeated hiddenfield. Look at the edit. I have added a hidden field and trying to assign value to a hidden field and get that value in c#. Provided code doesnt assign hidden field value.

Comment: unfortunately hidden field is not getting value.

rendered html is    
<div class="emoji-div" value="4"><table .....></table></div> <input type="hidden" name="dtlQuestions$ctl00$s" id="dtlQuestions_s_0">

Comment: update -- when i inspect i found that the last hidden field of repeated items is getting the value.

Comment: ye. since its rendered by ASP.net each hidden field will get name dtlQuestions$ctl00$s, dtlQuestions$ctl01$s, dtlQuestions$ctl02$s etc.. and id also will be different.

Comment: could you please help